# Operator Overloading TypeError: Missing argument

Tags: python

Here I have made a class and want to use `__add__(`) method to add 3 objects to form the 4th object by adding all the arguments of three objects.
When I add 2 objects to form 3rd object. It works fine but when I add 3 objects to form 4th object, It gives:

```
`TypeError: __add__` missing 1 required positional argument.
```

Plz see and tell me what I am doing wrong for making the 4th object by using 3 objects.

#To add 3 instance obj1, obj2, obj3 and make new instance obj4

```
    class Employee:
  def __init__(self, month1, month2, month3):
    self.month1_sal = month1
    self.month2_sal = month2
    self.month3_sal = month3

  def __add__(self, other, other1):
    obj4 = Employee(self.month1_sal+other.month1_sal+other1.month1_sal,
                    self.month2_sal+other.month2_sal+other1.month2_sal,
                    self.month3_sal+other.month3_sal+other1.month3_sal)
    return obj4


obj1 = Employee(10000, 20000, 3000)
obj2 = Employee(5000, 10000, 15000)
obj3 = Employee(20000, 30000, 40000)

obj4 = obj1 + obj2 + obj3
print(obj4.month1_sal) #output should be 35000
```

Error is:

```
  File "D:\Python Files\Begineer\OOP\etst5.py", line 17, in <module>
obj4 = obj1 + obj2 + obj3
TypeError: __add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other1'
```

Comment: The signature is usually `__add__(self, other)` (it's called when doing `self + other`). Is there a reason you've included a `other1` parameter? Where do you expect it to come from, exactly?

Comment: Note that `obj1 + obj2 + obj3` is evaluated as `(obj1 + obj2) + obj3` - so the method `__add__()` is called twice, once with args `obj1` and `obj2`, and then again with whatever the returned result of that was and `obj3`.

Comment: I am new to programming so please bear with me. in method __add__(self, other, other1), what I am thinking is. Self directs to the 1st object, obj1. other directs to the 2nd object, here obj2 and other1 directs to 3rd object, here obj3. and using all the object I wanted to form 4th object obj4

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy do you mean. a method can take max 2 arguments?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy So obj4 = obj1+obj2+obj3 is not possible. and I have to use add() method for every new object?